# The view disappear after changing its width many times

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, layout

I am trying to make simple Sticker View for Pictures Editing Project, but i am facing problem when I switch the sticker between the Views using:-
sticker.select(view);
when I select View for the first time its working good, but for the second time its change its position but the height and width still the width and height of the first View like the picture:-
[image]

full code:-

````
```class Sticker extends LinearLayout {
public Sticker(Context ctx)  {
super(ctx);
LayoutInflater thisLL = getLayoutInflater(); 
View thisVV = thisLL.inflate(R.layout.sticker, null);
this.removeAllViews();
((LinearLayout) this).addView(thisVV);
this.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT),(int) (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
selector = (LinearLayout)
thisVV.findViewById(R.id.selector);
/*rightP = (FrameLayout)
thisVV.findViewById(R.id.rightP);
bottomP = (FrameLayout)
thisVV.findViewById(R.id.bottomP);
pr = (LinearLayout)
thisVV.findViewById(R.id.pr);
pb = (LinearLayout)
thisVV.findViewById(R.id.pb);
*/
rotate = (ImageView)
thisVV.findViewById(R.id.rotate);
scale = (ImageView)
thisVV.findViewById(R.id.scale);
final Sticker stick = this;
rotate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                int ev = event.getAction();
                switch (ev) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        
                         
                        
                        break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        
                        break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        double r = (90 + (Math.atan2(event.getRawY() - (stick.getY()+(stick.getMeasuredHeight()/2)),event.getRawX() - (stick.getX()+(stick.getMeasuredWidth()/2))) * 180 / Math.PI));
                        if (-360 > r) {
                                r+=360;
                        }
                        r+=45;//to get smooth rotate
            stick.setRotation((float)r);
            selected.setRotation((float)r);
                        break;
                } return true;
        }
});

selector.setBackground(new GradientDrawable() { public GradientDrawable getIns(int a, int b, int c, int d) { this.setCornerRadius(a); this.setStroke(b, c); this.setColor(d); return this; } }.getIns((int)0, (int)2, 0xFF607D8B, Color.TRANSPARENT));
scale.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            PointF DivPT = new PointF(0,0);
            PointF StartPT = new PointF();
         private float initialTouchX;
                    float initialTouchY;
                    private int initialX;
                    private int initialY;
                    private int initialX2;
                    private int initialY2;
                    private int ex;
                    private int ey;
                    private int dw;
                    private int dh;
                    private float xx;
                    private float yy;
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View _view, MotionEvent event) {
                int n=event.getAction();
                if(n==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) drag=false;
                    if(n==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        drag=true;
                                xx=selected.getX();
                                yy=selected.getY();
                                //dw=stick.selected.getMeasuredWidth()-frame.getMeasuredWidth();
                                //dh=stick.selected.getMeasuredHeight()-frame.getMeasuredHeight()-rotate.getMeasuredHeight();
                            }
                            if (n != 0) {
                                    if (n != 2) {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                    float cx = this.initialX + (float)(event.getRawX() - this.initialTouchX);
                    float cy = this.initialY + (float)(event.getRawY() - this.initialTouchY);
                    float cx2 = this.initialX + (float)(event.getRawX() - this.initialTouchX);
                    float cy2 = this.initialY + (float)(event.getRawY() - this.initialTouchY);
            selected.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) (cx),(int) (cy)));
            select(selected);
            //selector.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (cx2),(int) (cy2)));
                                        }
                            this.initialX = selected.getMeasuredWidth();
                            this.initialY = selected.getMeasuredHeight();
                            this.initialX2= selector.getMeasuredWidth();
                            this.initialY2= selector.getMeasuredHeight();
                            this.initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                            this.initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
            return true;
            }});
}
LinearLayout selector;
FrameLayout rightP;
FrameLayout bottomP;
ImageView rotate;
ImageView scale;
LinearLayout pr;
LinearLayout pb;
public View selected;
public View previous;
boolean drag = false;
public void select(View v){
this.selected=v;
try {
if (!(v.equals(previous))){
try {
    ((ViewGroup)this.getParent()).removeView(this);
} catch (Exception exp65676) {
     
}
((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup)v.getParent())).addView(this);
}
this.selector.getLayoutParams().width = ((int)(v.getMeasuredWidth()));
this.selector.getLayoutParams().height = ((int)(v.getMeasuredHeight()));
/**/
/*
this.selector.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (0),(int) (0)));
*/
previous=v;
((View)(v.getParent())).invalidate();
float top=((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)(this.selector.getLayoutParams())).topMargin;
float left =((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)(this.selector.getLayoutParams())).leftMargin;
setX(v.getX()-rotate.getMeasuredWidth()); 
setY(v.getY()-top);
setRotation((float)(v.getRotation()));
} catch (Exception e) {
SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), (e.toString()));
}
}
private PointF DownPT = new PointF();
private PointF StartPT = new PointF();
private float SX;
private float SY;
private float rotation;
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //setRotation(0);
                    //selected.setRotation(0);
                    PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                    setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x));
                    setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));
                    selected.setX((int)((StartPT.x+mv.x)));
                    selected.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y+SY));
                    StartPT = new PointF(getX(),getY());
                    select(selected);
                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : 
                    DownPT.x = event.getX();
                    DownPT.y = event.getY();
                    rotation=getRotation();
                    //setRotation(0);
                    //setAlpha(0);
                    //drag=true;
                    StartPT = new PointF(getX(),getY());
                    //SX=getX()-selected.getX();
                    SX=rotate.getMeasuredWidth();
                    SY=getY()-selected.getY();
                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : 
                    setRotation(rotation);
                    setAlpha(1);
                    selected.setRotation(rotation);
                    select(selected);
                    drag=false;
                    break;
                    default : break;
                } return true;
} 
}```

xml file:

``` <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rotate"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/rotate"
            android:scaleType="fitStart" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scale"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/scale"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>```


}
LinearLayout selector;
FrameLayout rightP;
FrameLayout bottomP;
ImageView rotate;
ImageView scale;
LinearLayout pr;
LinearLayout pb;
public View selected;
public View previous;
boolean drag = false;
public void select(View v){
this.selected=v;
try {
if (!(v.equals(previous))){
try {
    ((ViewGroup)this.getParent()).removeView(this);
} catch (Exception exp65676) {
     
}
((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup)v.getParent())).addView(this);
}
this.selector.getLayoutParams().width = ((int)(v.getMeasuredWidth()));
this.selector.getLayoutParams().height = ((int)(v.getMeasuredHeight()));
/**/
/*
this.selector.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (0),(int) (0)));
*/
previous=v;
((View)(v.getParent())).invalidate();
float top=((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)(this.selector.getLayoutParams())).topMargin;
float left =((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)(this.selector.getLayoutParams())).leftMargin;
setX(v.getX()-rotate.getMeasuredWidth()); 
setY(v.getY()-top);
setRotation((float)(v.getRotation()));
} catch (Exception e) {
SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), (e.toString()));
}
}
private PointF DownPT = new PointF();
private PointF StartPT = new PointF();
private float SX;
private float SY;
private float rotation;
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //setRotation(0);
                    //selected.setRotation(0);
                    PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                    setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x));
                    setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));
                    selected.setX((int)((StartPT.x+mv.x)));
                    selected.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y+SY));
                    StartPT = new PointF(getX(),getY());
                    select(selected);
                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : 
                    DownPT.x = event.getX();
                    DownPT.y = event.getY();
                    rotation=getRotation();
                    //setRotation(0);
                    //setAlpha(0);
                    //drag=true;
                    StartPT = new PointF(getX(),getY());
                    //SX=getX()-selected.getX();
                    SX=rotate.getMeasuredWidth();
                    SY=getY()-selected.getY();
                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : 
                    setRotation(rotation);
                    setAlpha(1);
                    selected.setRotation(rotation);
                    select(selected);
                    drag=false;
                    break;
                    default : break;
                } return true;
} 
}
````

Comment: you use LinearLayout with />, you need write >, and put in linearLayout your objects

Comment: LinearLayout `@+id/selector`